# Why are my widgets not appearing in my Tkinter Notebook tabs?

Tags: python, tkinter

Attempting to make a GUI using Tkinter Notebook tabs. I'm able to use .grid() normally if I don't use the Notebook tabs, but the second I add them everything disappears.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root= Tk()
root.title("Mountain Care Pharmacy CMS")
root.geometry('600x800')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

note = ttk.Notebook(root)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(note)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(note)
tab3 = ttk.Frame(note)

note.add(tab1, text = "CMS", compound=TOP)
note.add(tab2, text = "Other")
note.grid()

ttk.Button(tab1, text='Import PBM file', command=getPBM).grid(column = 0 , row = 1, sticky = W)
ttk.Button(tab1, text='Import Direct file', command=getDirect).grid(column = 0 , row = 2, sticky = W)
ttk.Button(tab1, text='Create CMS', command=createReport).grid(column=3, row = 4, sticky = W)
tab1.grid()

reportType = StringVar()
ttk.Combobox(tab2, textvariable=reportType)
pbm_file_path = StringVar()
direct_file_path = StringVar()
pbm_entry = ttk.Entry(tab2, textvariable=pbm_file_path)
direct_entry = ttk.Entry(tab2, textvariable=direct_file_path)
pbm_entry.grid(column=1, columnspan = 2, row=1, sticky = EW)
direct_entry.grid(column=1, columnspan = 2, row=2, sticky = EW)

for child in tab1.winfo_children(): 
    child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)
root.bind("<Return>", createReport)

root.mainloop()
```

Is it because of how I'm calling grid() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are calling `tab1.grid()`. You should not call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` since you've added it to a notebook. The notebook is responsible for managing the visibility of the frame.

Comment: Ah makes sense, so Notebooks must have their own built in geometry manager?

Comment: @JakeHalopoff: yes. in effect, notebooks are a geometry manager.